# How to save a file using django's File object

Tags: python, django

I am using Celery to strip the audio from an uploaded video file. I want to save the audio file into my model where the video file is. So this is what I am trying:

```py
# model
class Video(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(
        validators=[
            FileExtensionValidator(
                allowed_extensions=["mp4", "mov", "flv", "mkv", "avi"]
            )
        ]
    )
    processed_file = models.FileField(
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=["flac"])],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

# celery task 
output_audio_file = str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + "/" + str(video_obj.pk) + ".flac"

ffmpeg.input(video_obj.file.path).output(
    output_audio_file,
    **{
        "ac": 1,
        "ar": 16000,
        "format": "flac",
    },
).run()

dj_file = File(open(output_audio_file))
video_obj.processed_file = dj_file
video_obj.save()
```

This raises the `Detected path traversal attempt in '/app/proj/media/49.flac'` exception. I also tried with the context manager, with the `video_obj.processed_file.save()` method. All of which raise `TypeError, AttributeError, UnicodeDecodeError` and so on. I feel like the answer could be so simple but I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay it turned out simple as I thought. Since that Django saves the path in the DB I just gave the path to the `FileField` instead, like so:

```py
video_obj.processed_file.name = str(video_obj.pk) + ".flac"
video_obj.save()
```

I don't need the `MEDIA_ROOT` since it is added by default.
Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/